# How to load JQuery into Chrome app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to use JQuery within a chrome app. However, when I try to use JQuery after loading it in, it does not work. It is supposed to just hide the element with the tag `test`. I do not know if this is a problem with the way I'm loading the JQuery js file, or if this is not allowed with chrome app.

app.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test").hide();
});
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>ImageRetriever</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <!-- This is where I'm loading the JQuery js file from -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>  
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <h1 id="test">Hey</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Manifest File:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "ImageRetriever",
  "short_name": "ImageRetriever",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "38",

  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/icon_16.png",
    "128": "assets/icon_128.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus", 
    "alarms",
    "storage",
    "webview",
    "<all_urls>"
    ],

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try closing you link tag:  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" /> also please post console error if any.

Comment: huehuehuehuehue

Comment: I think this is doable. Just make sure you define your jquery library in the [manifest.json file](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) as have been demonstrated in this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737281/how-to-add-jquery-plugin-to-chrome-extension-manifest-json). Now if you plan to use it in .html files, be sure to add the jquery library in your <script> tags as have been stated in this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858073/how-to-include-jquery-in-chrome-app).